# Песочница stack overflow

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Существует ли возможность поиграться с функционалом сайта Stack Overflow не навлекая гнев модераторов, возможность потерять репутацию и быть забаненным на веки вечная?

Короче говоря, существует ли "Песочница"?

Comment: Не заводили такой раньше. А с чем хотите экспериментировать? Если что-то простое вроде форматирования, можно прямо здесь в ответах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ни с чем конкретным и при этом со всем одновременно :)

Comment: [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/285206#285206)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отдельного сайта для того, чтобы тестировать функционал – нет, и, с большой вероятностью, не будет.

В прошлом, при необходимости, участники проверяли свои гипотезы напрямую на основном сайте или здесь, на Мете, координируясь при этом в чате.

Comment: кстати! вроде еще был чат песочница, но что-то найти не могу

Comment: @Grundy так можно новый чат создать и в бой.

Comment: @alexolut, не, там просто уже было куча всего попробовано

Comment: @Grundy не понял Вас. Повторите. Приём.

Comment: @alexolut, в том чате песочнице уже было много чего опробовано

Comment: @Grundy т.е. чтоб новые не писать, а смотреть уже на использованные? Так а смысл такой песочнице, в которой уже всё есть? Хочется же самому куличиков полепить, а не на чужие замки любоваться.

Comment: @alexolut. да, но там можно и самому куличики лепить, по уже успользованному

Comment: был бы ещё прям ОГРОМНЫЙ респект, если бы я мог запустить локальную копию SO или ruSO...